# did cobalt team release reference cobalt application with widevine?

Tags: cobalt

currently we got one issue that cobalt source_buffer feed different encrypted inpput_buffer at same PTS.
after decrypt them by widewine, we get wrong data to decode, the decrypted data also is different.

we have to verify which part is broken.
could you provide us cobalt(release 11) binary that can decrpyt with widewine and decode vp9?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question and provide some code to illustrate your issue?

Comment: This is caused by decrypting the data in place.  The drm system is trying to decrypt the decrypted data again, which leads to the error.

Comment: Does this answer solve the issue?